# Is it security vulnerability to disable the W3C when initializing the webdriver in cucumber

Tags: webdriver, cucumber, capybara

Because of web driver in compatibility and issue is calling non w3 standard command, w3c option is set to false in cucumber environment configuration.

```
    Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
      capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
        chromeOptions: {'w3c' => false}
      )
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, 
    desired_capabilities: capabilities)
    end
```

Does this causes any security problems ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no security issue with turning off W3C mode. Google is supporting both W3C mode and the legacy mode at the moment, although legacy will go away at some point.